# For loop over two data frames to extract item from one df and store it on other

Tags: python, for-loop, append, multiple-columns, haversine

I have two data frames `df` and `df_station`

`df`

LATITUDE            LONGITUDE
51.2161             -122.3111
52.0780             -122.1795

`df_station`

station     lon      lat
CBBC   -128.1567  52.1850
CWAE  -122.9547   50.1290
CWCL  -121.5047   51.1447
CWEB  -126.5431   49.3833

I have to create a  new column in df[`STATION`], which contains `station`. This station value is selected based as the minimum distance.

My code

```
station = []
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    lon1 = r['LONGITUDE']
    lat1 = r['LATITUDE']
    dist = []

    for i, v in df_station.iterrows():
        lon2 = v['lon']
        lat2 = v['lat']
        dist.append(haversine((lat1, lon1 ), ( lat2 , lon2), unit='km')
                    
    station.append(df_station['station'][dist.index(min(dist))])
       
# store station name
df['STATION'] = station
```

Error -- station.append(df_station['station'][dist.index(min(dist))])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Not sure how to use df_station in first for loop.

Desired result is the data frame df looks like this

`df`

LATITUDE            LONGITUDE    STATION

51.2161             -122.3111    CWDL

52.0780             -122.1795    CPXL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to dump the dataframe for this operation.

```
lat_lon = zip(df.LATITUDE, df.LONGITUDE)
lat_lon_station = zip(df_station.LATITUDE, df_station.LONGITUDE, df_station.STATION)

results = {}
for lat, lon in lat_lon:
    for station_lat, station_lon, station in lat_lon_station:
        dist = haversine((lat, lon ), ( station_lat, station_lon), unit='km')
        if station in results:
            if results[station] < dist:
                pass
            else:
                results[station] = dist
        else:
            results[stations] = dist
```

Does this accomplish your goal?

Zipping at the beginning should give a noticable improvement on runtimes for larger dataframes.

Comment: Additionally, since you are only iterating over the first zip once, you could make that an generator with izip instead. Also, I edited the code so that previously observations of a station are only overwritten if the result is smaller

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Thank you. I  am also doing 1)  Calculating the distance from each station 2)  finding the minimum distance 3)  finding the station that corresponds that minimum value and then storing it in `df`.

Comment: I updated the code - the only missing step is a df.station.map(results) call for your to get the final value back into your dataframe.